# How to best strip out certain strings in a file?

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

If I have a file with the following content:

```
11:17 GET this is my content #2013
11:18 GET this is my content #2014
11:19 GET this is my content #2015
```

How can I use a `Scanner` and ignore certain parts of a `String line = scanner.nextLine();?

The result that I like to have would be:

```
this is my content
this is my content
this is my content
```

So I'd like to trip everything from the start until GET, and then take everything until the # char.

How could this easily be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [String.indexOf(String str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) and [String.indexOf(char ch)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) methods. For example:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
int start = line.indexOf("GET");
int end = line.indexOf('#');
String result = line.substring(start + 4, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way might be

```
String strippedStart = scanner.nextLine().split(" ", 3)[2];
String result = strippedStart.substring(0, strippedStart.lastIndexOf("#")).trim();
```

This assumes the are always two space separated tokens at the beginning (11:22 GET or 11:33 POST, idk).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:-

```
String line ="11:17 GET this is my content #2013";
int startIndex = line.indexOf("GET ");
int endIndex = line.indexOf("#");
line = line.substring(startIndex+4, endIndex-1);
System.out.println(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best solution for your problem would be using [Java regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). Using regex you can define which group or groups of text you want to retrieve and what kind of text comes where. I haven't been working with Java in a long time, so I'll try to help you out from the top of my head. I'll try to give you a point in the right direction.

First off, compile a pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} GET (.*?) #\d+$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

First part of the regex says that you expect one or two digits followed by a colon followed by one or two digits again. After that comes the GET (you can use GET|POST if you expect those words or \w+? if you expect any word). Then you define the group you want with the parentheses. Lastly, you put the hash and any number of digits with at least one digit. You might consider putting flags DOTALL and CASE_INSENSITIVE, although I don't think you'll be needing them.

Then you continue with the matcher:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textToParse);
while (matcher.find())
{
    //extract groups here
    String group = matcher.group(1);
}
```

In the `while` loop you can use `matcher.group(1)` to find the text in the group you selected with the parentheses (the text you'd like extracted). `matcher.group(0)` gives the entire find, which is not what you're currently looking for (I guess).

Sorry for any errors in the code, it has not been tested. Hope this puts you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rather flexible solution:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("data"));
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.+?)\\s+(.+?)\\s+(.*)\\s+(.+?)$");
Matcher m;
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    m = p.matcher(s.nextLine());
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(3));
    }
}
```

This piece of code ignores first, second and last words from every line before printing them.

Advantage is that it relies on whitespaces rather than specific string literals to perform the stripping.